# new activity not being called from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

tha new dialog frament class is not being called y is this so ..?? it toasts the message as well as the toast in the exception

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   try {
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
     Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, FireMissilesDialogFragment.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", message);
     newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  //   Toast.makeText(context, "1"+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     context.startActivity(newIntent);
   //  Toast.makeText(context, "2"+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     e.printStackTrace();

    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't start a fragment via an intent - you need to start an activity